# RPC server with bitcoin-qt and bitcoind has a different set of commands?

Tags: client, json-rpc

When running `bitcoin-qt -server`, I am able to run the `getbalance` command, and the `help` command shows many items:

```
~ > bitcoin-qt -regtest -server  # Running in another shell

~ > bitcoin-cli -regtest getbalance
2797.99990000
~ > bitcoin-cli -regtest help | wc -l
69
```

Trying the same thing with `bitcoind` gives me fewer commands and no access to `getbalance`:

```
~ > bitcoind -regtest -server  # Running in another shell

~ > bitcoin-cli -regtest getbalance
error: {"code":-32601,"message":"Method not found"}
~ > bitcoin-cli -regtest help | wc -l
31
```

Is this a limitation of `bitcoind` or have I incorrectly configured it?

I'm using 0.9.1:

```
~ > bitcoin-cli --help | head -1
Bitcoin RPC client version v0.9.1.0-g026a939-beta

~ > bitcoind --help | head -1
Bitcoin Core Daemon version v0.9.1.0-g026a939-beta

~ > bitcoin-qt --help | head -1
Bitcoin Core version v0.9.1.0-g026a939-beta
```

Answer (score 2):

Just discovered the problem. It has to do with the "wallet" being disabled in the code via the default configuration with my package management.

I investigated the source initially and saw that there is a bunch of commands that are only enabled if the wallet #define is enabled: https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin/blob/e18bc583d41d97cdab93b7ffd111402628cfba19/src/rpcserver.cpp#L268

From there I was able to work out that the build options has disabled the wallet. I'm on Arch Linux, which the user-contributed package (on the AUR) has been configured to disable the wallet by default.

In other words, `PKGBUILD` configuration has added `--disable-wallet` to the  `./configure` arguments as you can see here: https://aur.archlinux.org/packages/bi/bitcoin-core/PKGBUILD

As if the time of posting, the `./configure` command is:

```
./configure \
    --prefix=/usr \
    --sbindir=/usr/bin \
    --libexecdir=/usr/lib/bitcoin \
    --sysconfdir=/etc \
    --sharedstatedir=/usr/share/bitcoin \
    --localstatedir=/var/lib/bitcoin \
    --enable-hardening \
    --with-gui=no \
    --disable-wallet
```

Modifying `PKGBUILD` by hand to remove the `--disable-wallet` argument fixes the problem.